C++ shared memory among forked processes (what do i do wrong)
I am making a basic program when the main process creates processes with fork that take the first element from a list and print it. I used boost library to manage shared memory, but this is my first time using such tools and i may have done things wrong.
#include <iostream>
#include <list>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>
#include <vector>
#include <boost/interprocess/shared_memory_object.hpp>
#include <boost/interprocess/mapped_region.hpp>
#include <boost/interprocess/sync/interprocess_mutex.hpp>
using namespace std;
using namespace boost::interprocess;


struct shared_data{
    interprocess_mutex mtx;
    list<int> qqueue;

};


void modify_list(shared_data*& sdat);


int main(){
    shared_memory_object shm(open_or_create, "shm", read_write);
    shm.truncate(sizeof(shared_data));

    mapped_region reg(shm, read_write);
    void* address=reg.get_address();
    shared_data* shptr=new (address) shared_data;
    
    vector<pid_t> processors;
    size_t num_processors=4;
    
    for(int j=1; j<8; ++j){
        shptr->qqueue.push_back(j);
    }

    for(size_t i=0; i<num_processors; ++i){
        pid_t pid=fork();
        if(pid==0){
            modify_list(shptr);
        }
        else if(pid>0){
            processors.push_back(pid);
        }
    }

    for (pid_t cpu : processors) {
        int status;
        waitpid(cpu, &status, 0);
    }
}






void modify_list(shared_data*& sdat){
    while(true){
        sdat->mtx.lock();
        if(sdat->qqueue.empty()){
            sdat->mtx.unlock();
            break;
        }
        int ff = sdat->qqueue.front();
        sdat->qqueue.pop_front();
        sdat->mtx.unlock();
        cout<<"Process: "<<getpid()<<" dequeued "<<ff<<"\n";
        cout.flush();
    }
}

I am getting the following output:
Process: 320 dequeued 1
Process: 320 dequeued 2
Process: 320 dequeued 3
Process: 320 dequeued 4
Process: 320 dequeued 5
Process: 320 dequeued 6
Process: 320 dequeued 7
Process: 321 dequeued 2

since 2 is already dequeued by process 320 why is it again dequeued by 321, while 2 only exists once in the list.

You did not actually tell the list to put its data on the shared memory. The std::list object contains a pointer to the head node in non-shared memory and both processes see their own copy of it. This is why you must also use the allocator that boost.interprocess provides

ho would i do this thing actually (tried something and had library_error)

To be portable, use boost::container::list with the appropriate allocator as explained here: https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_87_0/doc/html/interprocess/containers_explained.html#interprocess.containers_explained.stl_container_requirements

A std::list<int, boost::interprocess::allocator<int, boost::interprocess::managed_shared_memory::segment_manager>> may also work ... or it may be that std::list does not support such stateful allocators.

You can still use the answer I gave to your earlier question Shared memory among forked processes c++. Handily, it showed how to correctly specify allocators so that what you want works.
Basically, you NEED a managed segment unless you e.g. want to roll your own allocator (e.g. PMR on a block of memory pre-allocated). Also, consider using fixed size containers (boost::container::static_vector e.g.) to avoid allocating at all.
Here's your data structure mimicked:
Live On Coliru
namespace Shared {
    namespace bc  = boost::container;
    namespace bip = boost::interprocess;

    using Segment                     = bip::managed_shared_memory;
    using Manager                     = Segment::segment_manager;
    template <typename T> using Alloc = bc::scoped_allocator_adaptor<bip::allocator<T, Manager>>;

    template <typename T> using List = bc::list<T, Alloc<T>>;

    struct MyData {
        using allocator_type = Alloc<MyData>;

        template <typename A> MyData(A&& alloc) : qqueue(std::forward<A>(alloc)) {}

        size_t count() const {
            for (std::lock_guard lk(mtx);;)
                return qqueue.size();
        }

        void modify_list() {
            while (true) {
                std::lock_guard lk(mtx);
                if (qqueue.empty())
                    break;

                int ff = qqueue.front();
                qqueue.pop_front();
                std::cout << "Process: " << getpid() << " dequeued " << ff << std::endl;
            }
        }

        void print() const {
            std::lock_guard lk(mtx);
            fmt::print("  {}\n", qqueue);
        }

      private:
        mutable bip::interprocess_mutex mtx;
        List<int>                       qqueue;
    };
} // namespace Shared

Printing e.g. (on Coliru)
parent done

Process: 21371 dequeued 1

Process: 21371 dequeued 2

Process: 21371 dequeued 3

Process: 21371 dequeued 4

Process: 21371 dequeued 5

